# How to store elements in ONE array using TWO threads in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, synchronized

In my example I want to fill up *myArray* from indices 0 to 19 with integers from 100 to 119.

I want to use **two threads running at the same time**, one thread places values in the array from index 0 to index 9, the other thread from index 10 to index 19.

When I print out the elements of *myArray*, I expect to see this:

100
101
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
109
110
111
112
113
114
115
116
117
118
119

But because the threads are running at the same time, both can access my values, and I get the wrong result, this:

100
101
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
109
100
101
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
109

I think the problem is at my *addToArray()* method where the threads access my *aNumber* variable.

Is this when we need ***synchronized***? If yes, how?

Please see my code:

Main class:

```
public class ThreadMain {
    SimpleThread first;
    SimpleThread second;

    public ThreadMain(String firstName, String secondName) {
        first = new SimpleThread(firstName);
        second = new SimpleThread(secondName);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadMain threadMain = new ThreadMain("FirstThread", "SecondThread");
        threadMain.startThreads();
        threadMain.waitForThreadsToFinish();
        threadMain.displayArrayElements();

    }

    private void startThreads() {
        first.start();
        second.start();
    }

    /**
     * main thread sleeps while the other threads are working.
     */
    private void waitForThreadsToFinish() {
        while (first.isAlive() || second.isAlive()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void displayArrayElements() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
            int element = SimpleThread.getArrayElement(i);
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }
}
```

Thread class:

```
class SimpleThread extends Thread {

    private int startIndex;
    private int endIndex;
    private static int[] myArray = new int[20];
    private int aNumber = 100;

    public SimpleThread(String str) {
        super(str);
    }

    public void run() {

        if (getName().equals("FirstThread")) {
            startIndex = 0;
            endIndex = 10;
            addToArray();//store value of aNumber in myArray from index 0 to index 9.
        }
        if (getName().equals("SecondThread")) {
            startIndex = 10;
            endIndex = 20;
            addToArray();//store value of aNumber in myArray from index 10 to index 19.
        }
    }

    private void addToArray() {
        for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; ++i) {
            myArray[i] = aNumber;
            ++aNumber;
        }
    }

    public static int getArrayElement(int index) {
        return myArray[index];
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be better to change your method to `private void addToArray(int start, int end)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem appears to be that both instances of `SimpleThread` assign values beginning with a starting value of `100` and go from there.

One way to achieve your desired result, would be to use something like:

```
private void addToArray(int startIndex, int endIndex) {
    for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; ++i) {
        myArray[i] = aNumber + startIndex; // Change is here
        ++aNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: Clarification: the point would be to fill up half of the array with one thread and the other half with another thread to save time, the array contains integers in my example, but it could be String or anything else.

Comment: Rather than incrementing `aNumber` I think that doing `myArray[i] = aNumber + i;` would be cleaner